# Split comma separated column data into additional columns in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have comma separated data in a column:

```
Column 
------- 
a,b,c,d, n etc
```

I want to split the comma separated data into multiple columns to get this output:

```
Column1  Column2 Column3 Column4 ColumnN 
-------  ------- ------- ------- -------
a        b       c       d       n
```

How can this be achieved?

used Mysql 5.6.17

Comment: as I was in doubt if you wanted to show it or insert them, I have done it with both, I hope it works for you.

Comment: Is it always a comma-separated list of four items, or does the list have a variable number of items? If the latter, what is the maximum?

Comment: as far as I have understood since it is not explained well the question is that it is separated in 4 columns of a character, what I do not know if it is with a select or inserting it in a table I did it with both. EXAMPLE : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/138

Comment: we do not know number of columns

Comment: see the links in my answer to see if that is what you want. @Vlad

Comment: But how can we fix this problem when we have more value? https://i.imgur.com/jzM5mVW.png

Comment: that's hard enough

Comment: you can add more columns to the table, but it would be meaningless.

Comment: I have an idea so what you should do is modify the table by adding one more column with alter table.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own split function to do that.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR( x VARCHAR(255), delim VARCHAR(12), pos INT )
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos), LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),delim, '');
```

Use might like this, the second parameter determined which value of position you want to retrieve from the string.

```
SELECT
 SPLIT_STR(Column,',',1) AS a,
 SPLIT_STR(Column,',',2) AS b,
 SPLIT_STR(Column,',',3) AS c,
 SPLIT_STR(Column,',',4) AS d
```

Comment: Very good answer you have earned my vote, one question as you see my answer :)

Comment: But how can we fix this problem when we have more value? i.imgur.com/jzM5mVW.png

Answer (score 1):

## If you want to show it :

I would do it with a `SELECT` which through the `SUBSTRING` separate the columns and with its aliases rename it the name of the columns.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(patient_id,1,1) AS COLUMN1,
       SUBSTRING(patient_id,3,1) AS COLUMN2, 
       SUBSTRING(patient_id,5,1) AS COLUMN3, 
       SUBSTRING(patient_id,7,1) AS COLUMN4 FROM A;
```

**RUN EXAMPLE :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/134

[<kbd>RUN EXAMPLE</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/134)

## If you want that data in a table then do this

**First create the new table**

```
CREATE TABLE B(
  idA CHAR,
  idB CHAR,
  idC CHAR,
  idD CHAR
);
```

**And then through the `INSERT INTO` table `SELECT` you add it**

```
INSERT INTO B SELECT SUBSTRING(patient_id,1,1),
                     SUBSTRING(patient_id,3,1),
                     SUBSTRING(patient_id,5,1),
                     SUBSTRING(patient_id,7,1) FROM A;
```

**RUN EXAMPLE :** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/136

[<kbd>RUN EXAMPLE</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/136)

Even if you are adding data in the table in which all the data is, it will be added as in the following example

[<kbd>RUN EXAMPLE</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/138)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a query like this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n,m) 
AS (
      SELECT 1,3
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1,n*n 
      FROM cte_count 
      WHERE n < 100
    )
SELECT TRIM( BOTH FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, ',', n) ,',',-1) )AS single
FROM myTable m
JOIN cte_count cnt
WHERE
cnt.n <= LENGTH(mycol) -LENGTH(REPLACE(m.mycol,',','')) +1
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [test]> select * from myTable;
+----+----------------------------+
| id | mycol                      |
+----+----------------------------+
|  1 | a,b,c,d                    |
|  2 | Peter,Paul,Mary,john,David |
|  3 | one                        |
|  4 | one, two , three           |
+----+----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [test]> WITH RECURSIVE cte_count (n,m) 
    -> AS (
    ->       SELECT 1,3
    ->       UNION ALL
    ->       SELECT n + 1,n*n 
    ->       FROM cte_count 
    ->       WHERE n < 100
    ->     )
    -> SELECT TRIM( BOTH FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycol, ',', n) ,',',-1) )AS single
    -> FROM myTable m
    -> JOIN cte_count cnt
    -> WHERE
    -> cnt.n <= LENGTH(mycol) -LENGTH(REPLACE(m.mycol,',','')) +1
    -> ;
+--------+
| single |
+--------+
| a      |
| b      |
| c      |
| d      |
| Peter  |
| Paul   |
| Mary   |
| john   |
| David  |
| one    |
| one    |
| two    |
| three  |
+--------+
13 rows in set (0.004 sec)

MariaDB [test]>
```

Comment: that is wrong what he wants is to separate it in column not as you have it. That is to say that you have a,b,c,d in a column, so it should be four columns separated by commas.